# How to compare two Hashmaps

Tags: java

I have two Hashmaps filled here:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
try {
    properties.load(openFileInput("xmlfilesnames.xml"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
for (String key : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
    xmlFileMap.put(key, properties.get(key).toString());
}

try {
    properties.load(openFileInput("comparexml.xml"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
for (String key : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
    compareMap.put(key, properties.get(key).toString());
}
```

Declaration:

```
public Map<String,String> compareMap = new HashMap<>();
public Map<String, String> xmlFileMap = new HashMap<>();
```

they look like:

[image]

How can I check if the `job_id` changed of maybe if it's null?
Sometimes the job_id doesn't really exists. So the `job_id` is missing in them.

And Sometimes in `compareMap` are more then one `job_id`

How can I compare just the `job_id`'s and get a `boolean` value when compared?

Comment: How about `equals()`? `compareMap.equals(xmlFileMap)`. Assuming both your keys and values do have proper `equals()` and `hashCode()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that you want to find the map key based on specific pattern. This can be done by iterating over all keys:

```
private static String PREFIX = "<job_id>";
private static String SUFFIX = "</job_id>";

public static String extractJobId(Map<String, ?> map) {
    for(String key : map.keySet()) {
        if(key.startsWith(PREFIX) && key.endsWith(SUFFIX))
            return key.substring(PREFIX.length(), key.length()-SUFFIX.length());
    }
    // no job_id found
    return null;
}
```

If you may have several job_id keys and want to check whether all of them are the same, you can build an intermediate set instead:

```
public static Set<String> extractJobIds(Map<String, ?> map) {
    Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
    for(String key : map.keySet()) {
        if(key.startsWith(PREFIX) && key.endsWith(SUFFIX))
            result.add(key.substring(PREFIX.length(), key.length()-SUFFIX.length()));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now you can use this method to compare job_id of different maps:

```
if(Objects.equals(extractJobIds(xmlFileMap), extractJobIds(compareMap))) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! Awesome! so if the map isn't equal it returns null right? then I know that the maps aren't equal?

Comment: @korunos, if job_ids are different, then `Obejcts.equals` will return false.

Comment: and what do i get if just the order changed. assuming that both maps have two job_id's and they are equal. What if the job_id's of the compareMap changed the order?